# vb.net update query problem with ms access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

**Error: No value given for one or more required parameters.**

I can't find any problems with this code, please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
Public Sub update_bill_amount_2()
        Try
            Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath + "\" & frmHome.db_name & ".accdb")
            con1.Open()
            Dim strng1 As String
            Dim current_date As Date = Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy")

            strng1 = ("UPDATE [bill_details] SET [updatebillamount2] =" & Val(txtPaidAmount.Text) _
                    & ",[updatebilldate2] ='" & current_date _
                    & "',[totalpaidamount] =" & Val(lblPaidAmount.Text) _
                    & ",[status] ='" & stock_status _
                    & "' WHERE [billid]= " & OpenBillID & "")
            
            Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strng1, con1)

            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd1.Dispose()
            con1.Close()

            MsgBox("Bill Updated.", vbInformation, "Update")
        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.ToString, vbCritical, "Error - update_bill_amount_2")
            End
        End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use *parameters* (look it up, many examples) to avoid the mess.

Next, to answer your question, create a valid string expression for the date value:

```vb
Dim current_date As Date = Date()

            strng1 = ("UPDATE [bill_details] SET [updatebillamount2] =" & Val(txtPaidAmount.Text) _
                    & ",[updatebilldate2] =#" & Format(current_date, "yyyy\/MM\/dd") & "# " _
                    & ",[totalpaidamount] =" & Val(lblPaidAmount.Text) _
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work.. :(

Comment: And I used parameters but no results.

Comment: Print the finished SQL and run it manually to debug.